# How do I turn on template and block hints programmatically?

Tags: programmatically, template-hints

I know how to do it via `system->configuration->Developer` and on other sites people have mentioned doing it by setting `template_path_hints` to 1 in the `config files`.

I would have tried to copy the method used in the admin section but this wasn't so easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Most developers I know are using a module for enhanced template hints:

[AOE Template Hints](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints)

It allows you turn turn on template hints by adding "?ath=1" to the URL and will give much more detailed info than the standard version.

If you want to implement it yourself you could look at how this module does it:

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints/blob/master/app/code/community/Aoe/TemplateHints/Model/Observer.php#L37-L47

This method is called in an observer listening for the `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event.

Comment: Is there similar way available for magento 2 without the need to run the commands ?